# How to download video from embedded Vimeo blob link in webpage?

Tags: video, download, vimeo

I'm trying to download a video that contains a `blob:https://player.vimeo.com/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX` link. I've tried other options that have been explained on the site, but none have worked.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/)? Vimeo has been a supported site, at least in the past.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some figuring out on my own, I just changed the embedded blob link from:

*The X's below was the id that already existed in the link*

`blob:https://player.vimeo.com/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX` to
`http://player.vimeo.com/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`
(removed `blob:` and secure from `https`) and the link adjusted to the src of the video.

It looked something like:
`https://server-name.akamaized.net/.../XX/XXXX/XX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX.mp4`.

Opened the link in a new tab, picked the quality I wanted, and downloaded the video by clicking the vertical ellipses.

Comment: This does not seem to work for private sites. I've tried `wget` and it forwards to `https` and then returns `404 NOT FOUND`.

Comment: Here is a similar way for private videos: https://superuser.com/questions/1822603/how-to-download-an-embedded-private-vimeo-video/1822604#1822604