# How to download an embedded private Vimeo video

Tags: download, iframe, vimeo

Given an embedded private video with the player URL, e.g. `https://player.vimeo.com/video/874566064`

How can I download the video for offline viewing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vimeo serves video and audio separately and in chunks. The URLs seem to contain short-lived tokens that are only available to you when you are authorized to view the video.

1. Go to the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools
2. Hit the play button
3. Search the network log for `video` and `audio`
4. Get the respective URLs* and strip away the query parameters, e.g. https://6vod-adaptive.akamaized.net/.../parcel/video/466552c7.mp4
5. Download video and audio (e.g. using `wget <URL> -O <audio|video>.mp4`)
6. Merge video and audio with `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -c copy video_audio_merged.mp4`

[image: Screenshot of network tab in developer tools, highlighting the most often occurring file]

* Often, don't use the very first URL that appears, but the file that appears most often (i.e. `466552c7.mp4` in the screenshot above). The URLs correspond to the video resolution and the player will adjust it to your network connection.

Comment: …or use JDownloader. I can't test this one as I don't have the referrer/password.

Comment: I've just tried with the Firefox extension Video DownloadHelper and it produces corrupt files.

Comment: I've never used that, but I've never known JDownloader to fail. The session URL has expired so there was nothing I could fully test in this case.